# Repeating Rows (InfoPath) in SharePoint Column

Tags: 2007, infopath, column

I have a field in a repeating table in Infopath 2007 and I've saved the form to the document library and connected fields in the form to columns in the SharePoint site. The only options I see in SharrePoint when choosing properties for the repeating field are first, last, and count. First being first row and last being last row in my experience. Is it possible to see all the data in every row show up as data in my SharePoint column instead of just first, last, or count? Tank you!

Example:
FieldName = Pet

Field Data in Form:
Row1 = Cat
Row2 = Dog
Row3 = Mouse

I want to see Cat, Dog, Mouse in one cell in column named Pet not .......
(Last) Mouse
(First) Cat
etc.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a "Double Eval", http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/17505/60995.aspx and promote the fields to a SharePoint field. Once promoted, then it can be utilized.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll look more into this shortly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the advice to use double eval trick, it is probably better to refer to the [original (Infopath team) "doc"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/04/05/569338.aspx) on it (the title tells 2010 but it is really the updated article from 2006).

> I have a field in a repeating table in Infopath 2007 and I've saved
>   the form to the document library and connected fields in the form to
>   columns in the SharePoint site

If you getting repeating field through connection to a sharepoint column then you should have made from this column a site column and reuse it directly instead of promoting it through an Infopath.